# How does math.random work with exponents work in Lua?

Tags: lua

I am trying to get a random 16 digit number in Lua. What I have written isn't working out for me when logically it should. How does  math.random work with exponents?

This is what I keep getting.

```
 > return math.random(10^15, 10^16)
 > -1637272360
```

Comment: don't you think 10^15 is a too large value for any of lua's number types?

Comment: I am still brand new to Lua. Is there anyway I can generate a number like this?

Comment: You're probably using Lua 5.1. Try Lua 5.2, which is the current version. You can try it at the [live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a 16 digit number, try generating them this way:

```lua
local fmt = "%d%07d%08d"
local random = math.random
local num = fmt:format(random(1, 9), random(0, 10^7), random(0, 10^8))
```

and then keep the variable `num` in string type. As a number, it converts the values to exponential form(because of the very large; in your case `> 10^14`; exponential value) or otherwise, you can store them as a(n) Hex string?

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know that the cap is 10^14. Thanks!!

Comment: @finnw and how will there be leading zeroes?

Comment: Sorry my last comment was not very clear, but as an example, how could this function generate the value `1000000000000000` ?

Comment: You can avoid scientific notation with exponents by using `string.format`. The 14-digit limit is just used in `tostring`.

Comment: This should be using `("%d%d"):format(math.random(10^7,10^8), math.random(10^7,10^8))`, otherwise it may break if numbers are formatted in unexpected ways.

Comment: @LMD updated the code to better generation of exactly 16 digit numbers